# How can I remove unwanted human hair from clothing after washing?

Tags: cleaning, clothing

I was wondering how to remove **human** hair that builds up and sticks to my clothing? I've noticed this right after my clothes have been put away. Is there any way to remove or to prevent human hair from ever sticking to clothing?

Comment: Neither of these hints work for hair interwoven into your clothes.

Answer (score 2):

A more sustainable alternative is using tools specifically made for this task, the **clothes brush**, which I've always used to remove cat hairs from clothing. These are brushes with patches of a micro-Velcro-like material to which hairs and lint will stick:

[image]

There are similar utensils called *lint removers*, but I'm not sure if they are specifically helpful for removing hairs.

Answer (score 1):

Removal is easy. Get you a roll of duct tape, tear off a convenient length say 12" long, and then stick it against the clothing- let it grip for a moment- and then peel it off. The hair will stick well to the tape. You can reuse that same piece of tape many times until it is almost completely covered with hair and loose lint, at which point you throw it away and start with a fresh piece of tape.

Comment: To extend the life of the duct tape strip, shake the clothes a little, to remove at least some of the loose particles. Shake = move the clothes up-down in a whipping motion.